# Sequence of polynomials converging to a discontinuous function in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Is there a sequence of polynomials $P_n $ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P_n (z) $ exists everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ and equals to $1$ if $\text{Im} (z)>0$, $0$ if $\text{Im} (z) = 0$ and $-1$ if $\text{Im} (z) < 0$?

Intuitively, I guess such polynomial doesn't exist, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove it..

Comment: Perhaps your question could be reopened if you explained the background: where you are in the course, what theorems you've recently covered, what book etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think about compact sets

$$A_n = [-n,n]\times [-1/n,1/n], B_n = [-n,n]\times [2/n,n], C_n = [-n,n]\times [-n,-2/n]$$

and neighborhoods of them $U_n,V_n,W_n$ that are very close to $A_n,B_n,C_n.$ Do it right and $\mathbb {C}\setminus (U_n\cup V_n\cup W_n)$ will be connected. That should start ringing a few bells.

Comment: Ah sorry, I couldn't leave a reply for peronal problems.

Comment: I can choose a sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n $ in each $U_n\cup V_n\cup W_n $, converging to 1,0,-1. Then, by Runge's theorem, I can also choose a seq of polynomials $P_n $ such that $|f_n-P_n|<1/n $ uniformly in the described cpt sets. Thus the problem is solved positively, right?

Comment: You can actually make the $f_n$equal to $1,0,-1$ on $U_n,V_n,W_n.$ But yes, that is the right idea.